# Sublime Text regular expression to select a set of symbols at once

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have data like this:

```
    |['[(2* 0.60450588619793666)]',
 '[(2* 0.30587153147400686)*( 12* 0.31944983407468985)]',
 '[(5* 0.76392814534337561)]', '[(2* 0.72085131857293117)]',
 '[(11* 0.78549343211487599)]', '[(12* 0.76893561040584868)]',
 '[(8* 0.7 ...and so on ...
```

I want to eliminate  these **`| ' ( [ ] )`** symbols all at once.
I tried this `[['|()]` *regular expression*. It successfully removes all symbols except `]`.
How can I remove `]` as well?

Comment: this is a reserved symbol. You have to escape it by adding slash `\]` so as `\[`

Comment: Thanks @RomanMaksimov . That solved my problem. Should I delete this question according to stackoverflow guidelines?

Comment: Just add the `]` after `[`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It too works! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You <strike>have to</strike> can escape the square brackets `\[\]` and close the character class `]`, i.e.:

```
[|'(\[\])]
```

or, as @revo pointed:

```
[]['|()]
```

Comment: No, there is no *must*.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood your comment, could you please clarify it?

Comment: Yes, there is no must to escape square brackets.